# How to assign a dictionary key and value to a variable as a string C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to send  email and assign a dictionary key and value to a variable as a string .

```
public ActionResult SendContactUs(ContactUsModel model)
    {
        SendEmail sendemail = new SendEmail();

        string toEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ContactUsEmail"];

        var keys = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
            { "Firstname", model.Firstname },
            { "Lastname", model.Lastname },
            { "Email", model.Email },
            { "Orgnization", model.Orgnization },
            { "Message", model.Message }
        };
   //here i want to pass keys  to body as string 
        string body = keys ;




        sendemail.Send(new EmailModel()
        {
            Body = body,
            To = new List<string>() { toEmail },

       });

        return Json(new { val = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

for example i want to see the string body as

```
FirstName: scscd
LastName : dcdcdcd
Email : dcdcd@dsds.rfrfr
Message : vxvxcvxcvxcvxcv
```

Comment: If the only place you use the dictionary is for the email text, don't use a dictionary - just build a string?

Comment: Why even use a dictionary then ? Use String/StringBuilder as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Linq to construct a string:

```
string body = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, keys.Select(x=>$"{x.Key}: {x.Value}"));
```